# Event that triggers when code is changed?

Tags: javascript

Hi is there an event that detects changes to the js code so you could change the version number evertime you do something with the code

I am to lazy to change the version number on my site every time I work on it :)

Comment: You can use `push` hook in git for that I guess

Comment: Sure, lots, but it's impossible to recommend something without more information. Are you using a build system (webpack, ng, etc)? Are you using git? How are you deploying? If you're just live editing JavaScript files over FTP: not really.

Comment: Are you also lazy enough to avoid sharing the environment you are working on? :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this, which is the good news. The bad news is that the most appropriate method for your project will depend very heavily on the details of how your project is set up, what method you use to deploy it, and so on. Generally things like automatic version increments on deployment are done by CI/CD tools, and that's a large field. You'll have to do some research on your own, with your project specifics as well as your needs in mind, to decide on the best solution. For example, if this is a private project and you don't want to bother with semantic versioning you can simply increment a counter, whereas a more elaborate project might have more complicated requirements.

Your question is tagged with javascript, although it's not clear what package manager you're using (if any). If you're working with npm or yarn you can use push or commit hooks, which is perhaps the simplest option.